# Call a soap client's method using a string and an object

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I'm using an external open source project that provides me computation services that I create using a UI that it provides.

The project creates `web-service` endpoints automatically that I'm suppose to consume via my application.

My problem is that I **can't** interfere in the process. It's a black box that creates a service for me when I choose to deploy the project.

Each service has a bunch of different logical "private methods" that are exposed in the `wsdl` that's automatically created.

If I could create the service myself, I would create one an interface with an exposed method called Process that will have one general input request param and one general Response, something like:

```
public GeneralResponse Process(GeneralRequest request);
```

I want to create a generic out-point in my application which passes two parameters:

1.Endpoint Url to shoot the request to.
2.Generic request as an input param.

I'm using `C#` and the easiest way to consume a service is simply adding a `service-reference`, creating a `client` and calling the wanted method.
Since I don't want to add a client per service reference, I'll add a random one, change the client's endpoint address and shoot the `request`.

The problem with this approach is that the `client` generated will expose it's "private methods" and I don't want other programmers on my team to accidentally invoke them.

Bottom line:

Is there any elegant way to create a Generic `soap client` and invoke a method using a string? Similar to the way you call the `Invoke` method when you use `reflection`?

Something like this:

```
GenericRequest req = GetRequest();
SoapClient client = new SoapClient(endpointUrl);
GenericResponse res = client.Invoke("Process", req) as GenericResponse;
```